# Ошибка в манифесте

Tags: android, android-studio

Когда я меняю манифест на правильный и запускаю build, то оно автоматически меняется на неправильный и выдаёт ошибку, как это исправить? Прикрепляю скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вторая фотка как должно быть

Comment: А зачем тут uses-sdk? убери это

Comment: я его убираю, оно после build автоматически добавляется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь править сгенерированный файл, о чём вам IDE сообщает. После билда этот файл генерируется заново, удалив все изменения в нём.

Вам надо править не сгенерированный файл. Т.е. файл не из `build` папки.

Comment: Короче я удалил файл из папки и вставил правильный и всё исправилось, спасибо